# Github-flavored markdown mode: syntax highlight code blocks

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown-mode, gfm-mode

For example, if I have a markdown file with the following:

````
###This is my markdown file
here is some text.
here is my code block:

``` js
var accountdown = require('accountdown');
var level = require('level');
var db = level('/tmp/users.db');

var users = accountdown(db, {
    login: { basic: require('accountdown-basic') }
});

var user = process.argv[2];
var pass = process.argv[3];
var bio = process.argv[4];

var opts = {
    login: { basic: { username: user, password: pass } },
    value: { bio: bio }
};
users.create(user, opts, function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
});
```
````

How can I enable highlighting in the code block?

Perhaps it's unrelated, but org-mode can highlight source code blocks as follows:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
      'org-babel-load-languages
      '((python . t)
        (js . t)
        (R . t)))
```

Comment: The best you can do is using `gfm-mode` for `README` or more generally, all Markdown files, it will highlight the code blocks in one uniform color. The feature of highlighting them à la org-mode hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks, that is disappointing but good to know. The feature works great in org-mode, hopefully someone can implement it in `gfm-mode`

Comment: FWIW, I haven't turned this into an answer as one could still rip out the code responsible for this from org-mode and adapt it for your problem to turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 24):

Native syntax highlighting of code blocks is now part of the [current development version](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) of [Markdown mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).  Specifically, it works for those GFM or tilde-fenced code blocks for which the language name has been specified, like the JavaScript code block in your question.  You can toggle this mode with <kbd>C-c C-x C-f</kbd> (`markdown-toggle-fontify-code-blocks-natively`).  You can set the default behavior by customizing the variable `markdown-fontify-code-blocks-natively`.  For example:

```el
(setq markdown-fontify-code-blocks-natively t)
```

Comment: Why the hell is this not on by default?